# How to dynamically changing content and styling of a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on a project where my requirement is to provide the content of the page dynamically, which will contain different div or tables  and also i need to pass style for those divs at run time and those styles can be changed many number of times. I am using AngularJS for the project. I could find some [resource](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/change-style-dynamically-in-different-ways-using-angularjs/) where one of the properties of the css for that class which is applicabe to the div is passed using ng-model, but i want to pass my entire CSS properties, applicabe for that class(may be in the form of json) from a Textarea element of the page.

Appreciate any help in this regard. Many thanks !

Part of my code look like:

```
<div  ng-style="sampleStyle" class="col-md-6 ">{{sampleText}}</div>

<textarea ng-model="sampleText" cols="40">
</textarea>
<textarea ng-model="sampleStyle" cols="40">
</textarea>
```

format of CSS i want to pass is :

```
{
color: xxx; background: xxx; font-size: xx; ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi psylogic, I tried passing value to sampleStyle but it didn't work. Though it may sound redundant but  i also tried passing value to ng-style by brute force, but even that is not working for me.

View: 
<div  ng-style="sampleStyle1" class="col-md-6 head1">{{sampleText}}</div>
<button ng-click="setStyle()">Set Style</button>

Controller:
 $scope.setStyle = function () {
   $scope.sampleStyle1 = {};
   
   $scope.sampleStyle1 = $scope.sampleStyle;
   //console.log($scope.sampleStyle1);
  }


  
 
 
  <textarea ng-model="sampleStyle1" col="60"></textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ng-class` instead.

html:

```
<div ng-class="sampleStyle" class="col-md-6 ">{{sampleText}}</div>
<textarea ng-model="sampleText" cols="40"></textarea>
<textarea ng-model="sampleStyle" cols="40"></textarea>
```

**Edit:**

To dynamically bind a style literal to an element, you can't simply use an ng-model because angular will interpret it as a string, not an object. You need to first use `$parse` to create a js object on the scope and refer to it from ng-style.

html:

```
<div ng-class="myStyle" class="col-md-6 ">{{sampleText}}</div>
<textarea ng-model="sampleText" cols="40"></textarea>
<textarea ng-model="sampleStyle" ng-change="styleChangeFn()" cols="40"></textarea>
```

js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", "$parse", function($scope, $parse) {
  $scope.styleChangeFn = function() {
     $scope.myStyle = $parse($scope.sampleStyle)($scope);
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution ShaharZ, but it seems using your solution i can pass any class which is already existing in my css. whatever i am giving in text area sampleStyle this goes and bind to my class along with col-md-6. What i want is to pass dynamic styling like { font-size: 30px; color: red; padding:10px; margin : 10px; } from text area itself.

Comment: @NitinKumar sorry, misunderstood what you were asking. Updated my answer. Note that for purposes of learning Angular you can do this, but there's almost no practical reason to 2-way bind style info. There is a better solution by creating a custom directive, but this is simplest